# Comprarar XML en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo dos xml y deseo ver cuales campos fueron modificados, sin embargo el resultado no los está formateando tal como fueron ingresados:

```
DECLARE @xml1 xml ='<id>41</id><codigo>00054</codigo>';
DECLARE @xml2 xml ='<id>41</id><codigo>00054</codigo><idequipo>1</idequipo>';

SELECT * 
    FROM (
        SELECT T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as NodeName,
        T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') as Value
        FROM @xml2.nodes('/*') AS T(N)
        EXCEPT
        SELECT  T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as NodeName,
        T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') as Value
        FROM @xml1.nodes('/*') AS T(N)
        ) AS x FOR XML PATH
```

Su resultado es:

```
<row><NodeName>idequipo</NodeName><Value>1</Value></row>
```

Y lo deseo:

```
<idequipo>1</idequipo>
```

Alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cómo no se me ocurre ahora como "mapear" el valor de una de las columnas como nodo y la otra como valor, lo que puedo sugerirte es construir directamente cada nodo/valor de la siguiente forma:

```
DECLARE @xml1 xml ='<id>41</id><codigo>00054</codigo>';
DECLARE @xml2 xml ='<id>41</id><codigo>00054</codigo><idequipo>1</idequipo>';

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(STUFF(
    (
    SELECT ' <'+NodeName + '>' + Value + '</'+NodeName + '>'
        FROM (
            SELECT T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as NodeName,
            T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') as Value
            FROM @xml2.nodes('/*') AS T(N)
            EXCEPT
            SELECT  T.N.value('local-name(.)', 'nvarchar(100)') as NodeName,
            T.N.value('.', 'nvarchar(100)') as Value
            FROM @xml1.nodes('/*') AS T(N)
            ) AS x FOR XML PATH ('')
    ), 1, 1, ''), '&lt;', '<'), '&gt;', '>')
```

Y ahora sí, la salida esperada:

```
<idequipo>1</idequipo>
```

Con `' <'+NodeName + '>' + Value + '<'+NodeName + '>'` creamos el nodo de forma "ad-hoc" y luego usando `STUFF()` concatenamos todo para generar una única variable, lo único que nos queda es "des-escapear" los caracteres `<` y `>`.